# Bash loop with if not condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have say 100 text files of which 50 of them have file name starting with sshv2l and other fifty without sshv2l. I want to merge them in a loop like this (below) where I have two sets of merged files. For the ones with sshv2l, I did something like below, but could not merge files without sshv2l. How do I write if not condition within for loop in bash?

```
for f in sshv2l*; do
echo "Merging file :" $f
cat ${f} >> sshv2l_merged.fastq
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop code can just be replaced with single `cat`:

```
cat sshv2l* >> /path/to/sshv2l_merged.fastq
```

Now to grab all the files not starting with `sshv2l` you can use `extglob` negation glob:

```
# enable extglob
shopt -s extglob nullglob

cat !(sshv2l*) >> /path/to/not_sshv2l_merged.fastq

# disable extglob
shopt -u extglob nullglob
```

I have added some imaginary `/path/to/` path to make sure you keep `*.fastq` files outside current directory to avoid them getting concatenated in `cat` commands.

Comment: Thanks, I have added it in answer.

Comment: Thanks! Also shopt was not available readily, so had to do: `exec bash` then
 `source ~/.bashrc`.